# CodeIgniter - Returning uploaded file data

Tags: codeigniter

Im using codeigniters file upload library .... everything works fine except i want to output the uploaded file details.

I have the following code

```
$uploaddata = $this->upload->data('userfile');
foreach($uploaddata as $details){
    echo $details['file_name'];
}
```

The above code keeps erroring with the following

Message: Undefined index: file_name

Could someone let me know where im going wrong,

Cheers

Comment: Could you provide more code. The form validation, the full callback, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the problem, but I think it will help you if you first know "what is the content of $uploaddata" by writing: **var_dump($uploaddata)** just before foreach loop...

Comment: The results from the var_dump are very confusing .... it echoed the following ... array(13) { ["file_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(21) "Air-Max-1-Premium.jpg" } ["file_size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> float(63.78) } ["file_type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" }

Comment: I sent one comment, but it was wrong and I deleted it... I looked at my codes: $upload_data = $this->upload->data();               $file_name = $upload_data['file_name'];
                    $file_path = $upload_data['full_path']; I think you can not use foreach in that way, because in every cycle it will return it's content...

Comment: When i echo out $file_name, it just returns 'Array'

Comment: try this one: foreach($uploaddata as $detailkey => $detail){
    if (is_array($detail)){
        echo $detailkey ." = ".  $detail[0] ."<br>";
    } elseif(!is_null($detail)) {
        echo $detailkey ." = ".  $detail ."<br>";
    }
}

Comment: That works perfect if there is only one file ... what happens if there are multiple file fields with names like userfile[] ... it only echos out the information for the first file uploaded ... weird

Comment: As I know the best way to collect the files information in codeigniter is using of their recommended format that they used in their guide: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: And about "multiple file fields"... check this:  http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/110130/                     and this one : http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/71999/